# Is it okay to say “Excuse me, Ms.” to get attention from strangers who are women?

Tags: expressions, politeness, honorifics, hailnames

I was wondering that above sentence on title, 
“Excuse me, Ms.” is rude or not. I’ve watched a video on youtube about English titles, but “Excuse me lady.” is very rude to get attention from women, and “Excuse me ma’am”
is good for southern part of the U.S. whereas it sometimes feels uncomfortable in other area. I know that Sir. can use for all men regardless of age. I need native English speaker’s
correct and clear answer. Thank you !

Comment: "Excuse me, please" avoids this minefield.

Comment: Hello, Jaehyeon Kim, and welcome to EL&U. This may be a little basic for this site, and also perhaps Primarily Opinion Based. It depends on the geography of the native speaker.

Comment: Weather Vane Cascabel Thanks for answering! I forgot to ask one more. my American professor who came from Nevada often says, Mr.Jaehyeon or Ms.Jennifer like this. Jaehyeon is my first name. Is it a way to call someone friendly?

Comment: Wait a minute...I worked for a few years with Korean people with and the family name is _usually_ first. For me, Kim is a family name, and Jaeyeon a first name. I think your teacher is observing that convention, and trying to show respect for your culture. i.e., you seem to be putting your family name last, like westerners.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Jaehyeon, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: Cascabel I appreciate it. Thank you.                          Chappo Thanks for advising me! It’s the first time for me to use this page. I will visit the page you recommended !

Comment: @Chappo: I'm a native speaker, and I don't find it trivial.

Comment: @NateEldredge Point taken. In future I'll borrow the wording from Cascabel's comment "This [question] may be a little basic for this site", as *a little basic* doesn't have the patronising overtones of *trivial*. Nonetheless, the EL&U [Tour] page says "English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", which gives a good indication of the level that the site is aiming at. :-)

Comment: I think Weather Vane's comment is probably the best answer you'll get on this one.  It can even be helpful when addressing men, too, because even there, some people can be different than most, and also there are people whom are hard to be certain of at a glance.  Personally, I don't think it's off-topic necessarily, because of the sheer number of native English speakers I've seen get into trouble with various well-intentioned  utterances that started with, "Excuse me," and were followed by one to three words that were intended to be a friendly request for attention.

Comment: Addressing someone by a personal title followed by their given name is generally something that a teacher or instructor will do to try to strike a balance between friendly and formal.

Comment: One problem is that "Mizz" is never used by itself the way "Miss" sometimes is.